# How to add ASP.NET 5 template to Visual Studio 2013 Update 5?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm going to migrate to ASP.NET 5, and would like to give a try to it.

As you know installing new version of Visual Studio is a pain in the neck. Now I would like to know
Is it possible to add ASP.NET 5 template to my Visual Studio 2013?

**PS**: I know I can install both versions side by side ([+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)), but I'm curious to know about that.

Comment: I haven't tried this way. We need to install the DNX on you machine first because Asp.net 5 fully based on DNX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The ASP.NET 5 tooling only works with VS 2015. Even if you manage to get the project templates in VS2013 you will get no other tooling support because VS2013 doesn't know about DNX, design time host and everything else that is required for ASP.NET 5.

There are many more things than just the project template that would have to be added to VS2013 in order to get the ASP.NET tooling.

Answer (score 2):

Why is installing Visual Studio 2015 a pain? It's a stable release and it works fine side-by-side with VS 2013. I've been using this since the first CTP without trouble, as long as you don't *uninstall* any of the versions.

Also, Microsoft released [specific tooling](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48738) for developing ASP.NET 5 applications which only works on VS2015.

Comment: Agreed. I installed VS2015 side-by-side with 2013 when it was first released. The install was actually smoother than previous VS installs. No issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm afraid you have to bite the bullet and install VS 2015. ASP.NET 5 is not finished and we are still having to install updates to the VS tooling to support each new Beta (Beta 7 was released recently, here is the [announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/09/02/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta7.aspx)). It's easier for the ASP.NET 5 Tooling team to support a single VS version.

That being said, there are no guarantees that future updates to VS 2013 won't add this feature once ASP.NET 5 is released.

Comment: I suppose anything is possible, but I highly doubt you'll ever see ASP.NET 5 support in VS2013. ASP.NET 5 uses the Rosyln compiler, and trying to retrofit support onto VS2013 would be quite an undertaking. I just don't see the VS team ever devoting enough time and energy to that when if you're an MSDN subscriber you can just upgrade for free and if you're not, you can still use the free community edition.

Comment: Agreed it is unlikely. Roslyn has actually been available for VS 2013 (Not sure if it still is) as a separate install. They would need to add the NPM install too though.

Comment: Roslyn support in VS has nothing to do with ASP.NET 5. The tooling uses the Roslyn available in the DNX because Roslyn alone doesn't understand the ASP.NET 5 projects